# Get label text and set it to input value[Why does input value only get text before the space? ]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Why does input value only gets text before the space?

> "Test" and not "Test f data"

```
$('#form1').append($('<input type = "text" value='+$("#test").text()+'/>'));
```

See my [FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/17oqc9oq/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ,

```
$('#form1').append($('<input type = "text" value="'+$("#test").text()+'"/>'));
```

Wrap value inside `"`

The issue was due to browser treating first word as the value and others as the attribute,

```
`$('#form1').append($('<input type = "text" value=ok ok ok />'));`
```

when rendered will return ,

```
<input value="ok" ok="" type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

replace `value='+$("#test").text()+'` with `value="'+$("#test").text()+'"` for wrap value

```
$('#form1').append($('<input type = "text" value="'+$("#test").text()+'"/>'));
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lastuser/17oqc9oq/2/)